# What is gnome-terminal.wrapper?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I run command `gnome-terminal.wrapper` it open terminal similar to `gnome-terminal`.

What is `gnome-terminal.wrapper`? How it differs from `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: [This would be more helpful.](http://superuser.com/questions/468648/what-is-a-terminal-wrapper)

Answer (score 3):

To put it shortly, `gnome-terminal.wrapper` is a perl script that sets up the arguments for `gnome-terminal` and then runs `exec` call that spawns `gnome-terminal` with  those arguments.

[Wrapper scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript) are very frequently used to set up environment for different  applications and other scripts.

Loosely related to this question are [What is a terminal wrapper?](https://superuser.com/q/468648/418028) and [Ctrl-Alt-t opens root terminal instead of normal terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/719107/295286)