# Ctrl-Alt-t opens root terminal instead of normal terminal

Tags: command-line, root, terminator

I installed Terminator and made it my default terminal with [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used-in-unity), but now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> opens Terminator as a root terminal. How do I get it to open Terminator as a normal terminal?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a [bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Even if the icon and the title says that is a root terminal, you are logged with your username.

Comment: check your key bindings.  If you see the option for ctrl+alt+t, change the terminal from root terminal, to gnome-terminal, or whatever other terminal you want.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu see my answer. It's not a bug, it's just the way unity works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What happens ?**

**TL;DR #1**: Basically, you spawn `x-terminal-emulator` and Unity searches for anything that has `x-terminal-emulator` in their shortcut file.

1. You press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which spawns `x-terminal-emulator`. In Debian Alternatives system, `x-terminal-emulator` is a symlink to a whatever terminal emulator app you would want to use.
2. Unity's mechanisms search through the list of "shortcut" files in `/usr/share/applications`. It finds the `gksu.desktop` file, which has `Exec=gksu /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator` line and then takes out the line `Name=Root Terminal`. That `Root Terminal` is then displayed on the Unity's panel

**Why the same thing doesn't happen with gnome-terminal?**

**TL;DR #2:** `gnome-terminal` is actually spawned by a wrapper script, to which the default shortcut is linked.

When you run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` you are presented with choices, but none of them is `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`. Rather you have `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper` which is a perl script that sets up `gnome-terminal` first ! If you read through that script, at the end it has the following line :

```
exec('gnome-terminal',@args);
```

The `exec` call then spawns `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` , as separate app. Unity again searches `/usr/share/applications/` directory and finds `gnome-terminal.desktop` file which has `Name=Terminal` line, and it shows it on the launcher.

**What can be done?**

**TL;DR #3:** reassign keyboard shortcut,use custom wrapper, or create custom `.desktop` file. I recommend the `.desktop` way.

Easiest way is to reassign the shortcut. Use gsettings for that

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'sakura'
```

But that still doesn't solve the quirk with Unity's dash. My preferred solution is to create the custom `.desktop` file `/usr/share/applications/x-terminal-emulator.desktop` with the following contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MY CUSTOM TERMINAL
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
```

That way , you don't have to change anything, but Unity will display `MY CUSTOM NAME` on the launcher.

Third way, if you are feeling adventurous is to write a wrapper script, something like this:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /path/to/terminal-emulator ${1+"$@"}
```

Then you can add it as one of the options in the alternatives system using

```
sudo update-alternatives   --install /path/to/wrapper name /path/to/wrapper priority
```

Side note: priority is an integer, such as 10.

**More info**

- [Ubuntu Manpage: update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)
- [Wrapper Script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript)
- [What is a terminal Wrapper ?](https://superuser.com/questions/468648/what-is-a-terminal-wrapper)

Answer (score 7):

I tried the following link : https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1447580.

And run the following command and it worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'terminator'
```

Good luck!!